# XenCenter: how can I find the storage repository size of VM?

Tags: c#, api, citrix, xen

I have written a c# application for gathering all XenCenter VMs and populating a database with VMs information for my project. 
It looks like this

```
           // Establish XenCenter session
            session = new Session(HostName, 80);

            // Authenticate with username and password. The third parameter tells the server which API version we support.
            session.login_with_password(XenUserName, XenPassword, API_Version.API_1_3);

            List<XenRef<Host>> pools = Host.get_all(session);

            foreach (XenRef<Host> pool in pools)
            {
            // Get all records associated with this specific VM server
                Host host = Host.get_record(session, pool);

           // Get all records associated with this specific VM server resources.
                List<XenRef<VM>> residentVms = host.resident_VMs;
          foreach (var vm in residentVms)
           {
            VM vmRecord = VM.get_record(session, vm);      

           }
```

From vmRecord I can get some data like RAM size, Operation system, description and etc. But I can't get SR (storage repository) size.

Thanks in advance.